# Using Python Opensource Libraries to check users who visited a store

Tags: python, shapefile, open-source-gis, intersection, fields-attributes

I have a few files with location information:

1) User Lat Long Pings in Parquet Files (can be converted to CSV) format - this contains userid, timestamp, lat and lon
2) US County/State Shapefile
3) Store Centroid Data - centroid of stores like Walmart

Our goal is to:
1) Add geo attributes like county and state to user pings from county shapefile
2) Identify users who visited the store

Challenges:
1) Scale - User data has 30 million rows per day (over 6 months)

Can you please guide me on which geospatial libraries to use in order to create an efficient workflow? I briefly explored Fiona, Shapely, Geopandas.

I need to import the CSVs, shapefiles; define projections; create buffers; intersect them to get attributes and then output them. And I need to be able to do this at scale

Please let me know if my question is too vague

Comment: Using your first choice library where did you get stuck on your first step?  That is the kind of question suitable for our focussed Q&A format.

Comment: Is parallel processing available to you? That changes the problem considerably. This problem might be better suited as a hadoop tagged question on stack overflow, as there are definitely some workflows where you can solve this directly in hadoop. The Parquet -> CSV workflow may actually be your biggest bottleneck, since the rest of your problem can be solved at scale with proper sharding at that step.